# Extending resident permit in Germany using another passport

Tags: germany, resident-permit

I am an international student in Germany. I believe I will finish my study at the end of February. After that, I plan to extend my resident permit. However one of my passports will expire, I plan that use another valid passport to extend the resident permit. The question is, can I? Since the last time I extended my resident permit, I use my old passport, I don't know if there is any binding between passport and resident permit.

**Edit**

I am from Hong Kong, so I have a Hong Kong passport and a British National Oversea (BNO) passport.

Comment: The snswer may depend on the reason why you have more than 1 passport (same citizenship etc).

Comment: Residence permits are based on the person. A change of citizenship leads to a change in your file. They may ask which citizenship you wish to use (for the residence permit) in the long term. So make your renewal application and inform them of the situation. For Hong Kong, where this situation should be well known, this should cause no big problem.

Comment: Can you not replace the expiring passport?  Your dealings with the German authorities will surely be simpler if you do.

Answer (score 0):

The process is called Übertragung and you need to make an appointment with the Ausländeramt to do the change. The permit is always linked with the passport and expires with it.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).